# Pass multiple strings to function c

Tags: c, arrays, string, function

I'm learning the basics and principles of C.

I came now to pointers, strings and structs.

Now I'm working on this code to pass arrays' content to functions.

I have this code to pass content of different arrays to function.

What I succeeded to accomplish is:

1. How to pass one complete string because it's considered as one element of the array.
2. How to pass array of char and ints.

The issues I have now:

1. How to pass arrays of multiple strings to functions.
2. How to assign a pointer to the arrays to pass them also to functions.

This is my code so far:

```
void print_array(char *arr,int8_t cnt);
void print_array(char *arr,int8_t cnt)
{
    int i;
    printf("Number of elements is: %d\n",cnt);
    for (i=0;i<cnt;i++)
    {

        printf("Elements of array: %s\n",arr);
    }
}

void print_len (char *arr,int8_t cnt);

void print_len (char *arr,int8_t cnt)
{
    char i,l;
    for (i=0;i<cnt;i++)
    {
        printf ("%d\n",strlen(arr));
    }
}

int main(){
char  array_1 [] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
char  array_2 [] = {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F','G'};
char *array_3 [] = {"1st","2nd","3rd","4th","5th","6th"};
char *array_4 [] = {"Many of the designations used by manufacturers"};
char *array_5 [] = {"mm","End of Multiple Strings Array","simple bluetooth connection",
"datalogging purposes and accessing recorded data","THE OPERATING ENVIRONMENT"};
//int8_t *array_pointer[3]=(char*){&array_1,&array_2,&array_3};
int8_t cnt1 = sizeof(array_1)/sizeof(array_1[0]);
int8_t cnt2 = sizeof(array_2)/sizeof(array_2[0]);
int8_t cnt3 = sizeof(array_3)/sizeof(array_3[0]);
int8_t cnt4 = sizeof(array_4)/sizeof(array_4[0]);
int8_t cnt5 = sizeof(array_5)/sizeof(array_5[0]);
int8_t len1,len2,len3,len4,len5,i,t=0,x=0;
//print_len(*array_3,cnt3);
print_len(*array_5,cnt5);

//printf("Number of chars int the string#%d is: %d\n",i,t);

// this for testing strlen inside main
// I want to process this function outside main
/*for (i=0;i<cnt5;i++)
{
    printf ("%d\n",strlen(array_5[i]));
}*/


//print_array(array_pointer[0],cnt1);
//print_array(array_1,cnt1);
//print_array(array_2,cnt2);
//print_array(*array_3,cnt3);
//print_array(*array_4,cnt4);
print_array(*array_5,cnt5);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: what do yo mean by array of multiple string?

Comment: Please don't include swathes of commented out code — and don't include the definitions of variables that are consequently unused.  Note that `strlen()` returns a `size_t` value and the correct `printf()` format modifier is `z`: `%zu` is more correct than `%d`.  You may get away with it on a 32-bit machine; you may run into problems on 64-bit machines.

Comment: I just thought of that readers would see the examples I'm working with too. Also I wanted that readers would see the skills I have so they understand my question more. Anyway, you're right! Maybe readers would appreciate the skills already. But strlen works ok inside main, why it doesn't outside? Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. How to pass arrays of multiple strings to functions.

You need another function. Declare it as:

```
void print_array_2(char *arr[], int cnt);
```

Then, you can use:

```
print_array_2(array_3, cnt3);
```

> 2. How to assign a pointer to the arrays to pass them also to functions.

You can use:

```
char* string_array[2] = {};
string_array[0] = array_1;
string_array[2] = array_2;
print_array_2(string_array, 2);
```