# Pass parameters to the function in C

Tags: c, getopt

I am writing a function in `C` to open the serial port and read the flash data in a chip. I want to pass the serial port parameters to this function and open `COM 4`. 
I have tried to use these method to call the function:

1. `ret = download_main(1,'-C'+ 4);`
2. `ret = download_main(1,'-C4');`
3. `char  array_1[] = { "-C4"};`
   `ret = download_main(1, array_1);`
4. `ret = download_main(1, "-C4");` and change function definition to `int download_main(int argc, char *argv)`
5. `char *args[] = { "-C4", NULL };`
   `ret = download_main(1, args);`

but all failed to pass the parameter to this function and open the `COM4`.

**Function call**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int ret;    

char* COMx = "com4";
FILE* fp;

printf("open com!\n");

/** Open Com */
if ((fp = fopen(COMx, "wb+")) == NULL) {
    printf("Open %s Failed!\n", COMx);
}

/** Send "Hello,world!" */
fwrite((char*)"Hello,world!", sizeof("Hello,world!"), 1, fp);


char *args[] = { "-C4", NULL };
ret = download_main(1, args);
return ret;
}
```

the function called:

```
int download_main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
BOOL fSuccess;
TCHAR commPort[16];
TCHAR *numStr;
int len, i,ch;
int poweroff_param;
char *optstring = "C:c:r:F:f:P:w:b:B:R:A:l:h";
bininfo_node *bin_info = NULL;

opterr = 1;
if (argc < 3)
{
    usage();
    return 0;
}


optind = 0;
while((ch=getopt(argc,argv,optstring))!=-1)
{
    switch(ch)
    {
        case 'c':
            g_calibrate_switch = atoi(optarg);
            if(1 == g_calibrate_switch)
                printf("burn flash then entry calib mode\n");
            break;
        case 'C':
            numStr = optarg;
            len = _tcslen(numStr);
            for (i = 0; i < len; i++) 
            {
                if (!_istdigit(numStr[i])) 
                {
                    TRACE("Error: Invalid COM number: %s", numStr);
                    g_dldtool_exit_code = EXIT_CODE_COM_NUM_ERROR;
                    goto _exit;
                }
            }
            _stprintf_s(commPort, sizeof(commPort) / sizeof(TCHAR), "\\\\.\\COM%s", optarg);
            break;
```

There is no compiling error in this program. When I debug this program, it keeps exiting with code 0 and reminding me to add parameters to the function without going through the breakpoint in the `download_main` function like below:

[image]

Comment: change `int download_main(int argc, char *argv[])` this to `int download_main(int argc, char *argv)` and pass params like this `ret = download_main(1,"-C4")`. If you intended to pass more than one string then your prototype is correct.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38811014/pass-multiple-strings-to-function-c this might help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass multiple strings to function c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38811014/pass-multiple-strings-to-function-c)

Comment: You are aware that `'-C4'` is not a string, right...?

Comment: @kiranBiradar If the function `getopt` shall be used, it would be better not to change `argv` to a simple pointer.

Comment: I have tried your method , but not working, the program still remind me to pass the parameters.

Comment: Please always provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For being minimal, there is no need to show us the `binlist` part. For being complete you need to show us how you call the function,

Comment: What is `'-C'+4`expected to be? Hint: It is an integer. Not an array of strings

Comment: @Gerhardh I did not notice Op is using `getopt`. You are right.

Comment: @CreateFile did you see if (argc < 3) { usage(); return 0; } you got to pass atleast 3 arguments.

Comment: You must learn to distinguish different types of failure. Some of your errors are syntax errors that the compiler tells you. Others are runtime errors which can be found using a debugger.

Comment: BTW: "Using a debugger" means you should step through your code and see where you come along. Not just load into debugger and run it.

Answer (score 1):

As you seem to use the same mechanism as `main` does, you must prepare your strings properly:

```
char *args[] = {"download_main", "-C4", NULL};
ret = download_main(2, args);
```

Update:
As @rici pointed out, setting `optind=0` before scanning doesn't mean that the first argument is passed by `getopt`. Therefore you must provide an additional first argument. Normally this holds the name of the program when `main` is called with argument list, but for your own function call it doesn't matter what is in that first string.

Comment: still not working...... the program still remain me to pass parameters.

Comment: @CreateFile Can you post the compiler error you are getting with Gerhardh answer ?

Comment: @CreateFile did you see `if (argc < 3)
{
    usage();
    return 0;
}` you got to pass atleast 3 arguments.

Comment: @CreateFile at least it should compile without errors. If your function tells you to add parameters, you need to rethink your check for parameters (`argc<3`) as @kiranBiradar mentioned. Using a debugger you should see the reason for this within seconds. Please always use a debugger first.

Comment: Since `download_main` is simulating a top-level main function, it is expecting the first element in the `argv` array to be its name. It uses `getopt` to parse its argument list, and that will start with `argv[1]`. So you need `char *args[] = {"download", "-C4", NULL}; ret = download_main(2, args);` or some such; the first element is arbitrary.

Comment: @gerhardh: setting optind to 0 resets the scan, but it will still start at argument 1. (At least with glibc's getopt. Posix says the behaviour is unspecified.)

Comment: @rici, you are right. I didn't know that detail. I've updated the answer.